# How to set pickerview horizontally

Tags: swift, uipickerview

The default scroll setting for a UIPickerView is set to vertical. Is it possible to implement a UIPickerView horizontally in swift (picker view
containing array has to also change to horizontally)

without using any third party file

If so, could you please show me a sample
code is below

```
self.rangePickerView.hidden = false
self.rangePickerView.dataSource = self
self.rangePickerView.delegate = self

rangePickerView.clipsToBounds = false        
rangePickerView.layer.borderWidth = 0        
rangePickerView.dataSource = self
rangePickerView.delegate = self

self.rangePickerView.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width * 0.06,screenSize.height *
            0.02,screenSize.width * 0.89,screenSize.height*0.46)
self.rangePickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.rangePickerView.transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

self.view.addSubview(rangePickerView)        


//delegate methods//////

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
     return titles.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?      
{
    return titles[row]as String  
} 

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    print("Your favorite city is \(titles[row] )")
    rangePickerView.hidden = false
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 200  
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: There is no way to change this behavior  in a standard UIPickerView
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPickerView

Comment: ok thanks so i have option of akpickerview third party file and i want to use these for two pickerview each picker view conatin differnt text so how can do that  your respose is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

See this link for how to do this without a third party file, by transforming the picker view - http://torishere.github.io/swift/2015/02/12/horizontal-uipickerview.html
Otherwise, use AKPickerview for horizontal selection and use the tag property to distinguish between the two AKPickerviews that you want to have. So in pickerView(titleForItem) for example, check if pickerView.tag == 0 or tag == 1 and return different strings for the title.